# PHP Anti-DDoS by redirecting to secondary domain

Tags: php, ddos

I want to know if redirecting to a secondary domain when primary server reaches X ram due to request flood would be a possible way of mitigating an attack.
Idea:

```
Domain.one/antiddos.php
>check ram if > X -> redirect to secondary domain + hash
domain.two/antiddos.php?hash=XXX
hash = IP + timestamp + requestid hashed somehow together
```

second website prompts captcha and if right registers a token to be able to register on main website.

Comment: A DDoS attack is directed at your servers IP address. It doesn't go through your website (PHP). It's completely pointless to try and redirect an attack towards another IP with PHP. Usually DDoS attacks are "solved" by putting many servers into a cluster so the load can be balanced. Since this can be quite expensive, there are solutions like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Comment: In an enviroment where javascript and third services are not available and not usable, how do you set many servers to balance the requests?

Comment: For that I'll gladly direct you towards [Google](https://www.google.com). Perhaps they can help you at [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). But I would carefully read their Help section first so you can formulate your question correctly. Stack Overflow is about programming. Problems directly related to code. Your question has nothing to do with that, so we can't help you any further.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it most likely belongs on SE Information Security.